# Implicit conversion to array index type

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

Let's say I have following type:

```
struct XY
{
  short nIndex;
  
  constexpr operator int()
  {
     return nIndex;
  }
};
```

What can I change to make the following work:

```
char arr[10][255];

constexpr XY xy{1};

char *x = arr[xy];
```

I thought that just giving `XY` a convert-to-int operator would be enough but I'm getting the error:

> no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'const char [10][255]'
> and 'const XY')

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't resist: Is this a case of [The XY Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) ‎

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the variable is `constexpr`, you cannot call the conversion operator that is not const-qualified. Solution is simple: Make the conversion operator const qualified:

```
constexpr operator int() const
```

Comment: Didn't expect the problem to be solved as simply. It worked. Thanks.